# How to derive the equation for a bézier curve

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions, bezier-curve

So, I remember a while back there was a maths competition and we were given a curve that we needed to write an equation for. I just skipped the question since I didn't even know where to begin. I remember it was one among the last few questions of the paper and it was worth a *lot* of points.

I don't really remember what the curve looked like; it was something spirally, but I can't recall it to save my life right now.

So, I drew this curve in Inkscape (it's a Bézier curve. Or a few of them linked together, according to Wikipedia. If it's required I will post the whole path). And I would like to write the equation for it (with someone's help, obviously).

[image: The Bézier Curve]

---

I was always a bit bad with curves, graphs and lines, but I want to understand them better. So, I was hoping someone could explain the process of deriving the equation for a curve.

P.S: I'd like it if you could use another curve (it can be something simpler, but try avoiding something overly complicated) so I can crack this one on my own, but if you feel like using this curve as an example I won't mind.

---

### EDIT

So  have been browsing the internet, read a few Wikipedia entries about Bazier curves, and I understand how they're drawn (mostly the GIFs helped, haha), but I am still stumped when it comes to mathematically representing a Bézier curve. Also, I will add this image, which is the path and its control points (at the end of the blue lines; I didn't paint them in):

[image: The Path]

And also, the contents of the .tex file for the shape.

```
%LaTeX with PSTricks extensions
%%Creator: 0.48.2
%%Please note this file requires PSTricks extensions
\psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
\begin{pspicture}(451.46875,34.25392151)
 {
 \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{1 0 0}
 \pscustom[linewidth=3,linecolor=curcolor]
 {
 \newpath
 \moveto(450.48448,1.10834551)
 \curveto(404.89404,41.45133951)(333.34998,42.21654151)(281.90128,9.03018551)
 \curveto(258.09407,-6.32636849)(228.42388,9.91159551)(202.75741,15.38398551)
 \curveto(145.68728,27.55199551)(85.852286,40.32786151)(28.08402514,26.23698551)
 \curveto(18.5710181,23.91656551)(9.403556,20.24334551)(0.681686,15.78116551)
 }
 }
 \end{pspicture}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linear Bézier curve is simply a line given by parametric equation $R(t) = A+t(AB)$ , A being initial point and B being final point.

For Quadratic Bézier curve, take a look at the following picture.
[image]
Let the point between $P_1$ and $P_0$ be $Q_1$ and $P_1$ and $P_2$ be $Q_2$. Let our path be traced by $Q_0$. Then from above figure.
$$ \frac{P_0Q_1}{P_0P_1} = \frac{P_1Q_2}{P_1P_2} = \frac{Q_1Q_0}{Q_1Q2} = t \text{ (say)} $$
$$Q_1 = P_0 + t(P_0P_1), Q_2 = P_1 + t(P_1P_2)$$
So we have
$$Q_0 = Q_1 + t(Q_1Q_2) = P_0 + t(P_0P_1) + t(P_1 + t(P_1P_2) - (P_0 + t(P_0P_1)))$$
Have a look at more elaborate [article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

Comment: Oh, this actually demystifies Bézier curves a little, but I still don't understand—I am not sure what I don't understand. *sigh*

Comment: what are you trying to do?? For given points, I can explain higher order Bezier curves ... not sure without these points.

Comment: A very nice introduction is given at https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/